# Python - Tkinter label update values problem

Tags: python, tkinter, label

When I move the slider down to lower value (for example to 40), the third digit in the label remains displayed?

How can I solve this problem?

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):

        
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    
    # BMP display
    def bmp_print(*args):
        self.bmp_number = tk.Label(self, text=[self.w1.get()], fg = 'red', font=('Times', 60))
        self.bmp_number.place(x = 725, y = 140)
        
    
    # self windows size
    window_width = 1024
    window_height = 600

    # get the screen dimension
    screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()

    # find the center point
    center_x = int(screen_width/2 - window_width / 2)
    center_y = int(screen_height/2 - window_height / 2)

    # set the position of the window to the center of the screen
    self.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')
    
    # Resize main window xy, on/off,  0 or 1 .
    self.resizable(0, 0)
    
    # Main window on top of stack.
    self.attributes('-topmost', 1) 
    
    # Create slider
    self.w1 = tk.Scale(self, from_=240, to=40, command = bmp_print)
    self.w1.set(240)
    self.w1.place(x = 150, y=400)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = App()
  app.mainloop()
```

It is expected that when the result goes from a three-digit value to a two-digit value, the label displays the two-digit value, without the remaining third digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I move the slider down to lower value (for example to 40), the
> third digit in the label remains displayed?

Move `self.bmp_number` outside of function and  add `self.bmp_number.configure` inside  `bmp_print(args)` function.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):

        
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    
    # BMP display
    def bmp_print(args):
        #self.bmp_number = tk.Label(self, text=self.w1.get(),from_ = 0, to =10, fg = 'red', font=('Times', 60))
        #self.bmp_number.place(x = 725, y = 140)
        self.bmp_number.configure(text=args)
        
    
    # self windows size
    window_width = 1024
    window_height = 600

    # get the screen dimension
    screen_width = self.winfo_screenwidth()
    screen_height = self.winfo_screenheight()

    # find the center point
    center_x = int(screen_width/2 - window_width / 2)
    center_y = int(screen_height/2 - window_height / 2)

    # set the position of the window to the center of the screen
    self.geometry(f'{window_width}x{window_height}+{center_x}+{center_y}')
    
    # Resize main window xy, on/off,  0 or 1 .
    self.resizable(0, 0)
    
    # Main window on top of stack.
    self.attributes('-topmost', 1)

     
    
    # Create slider
    self.w1 = tk.Scale(self, from_=240, to=40, command = bmp_print)
    self.w1.set(240)
    self.w1.place(x = 150, y=400)

    self.bmp_number = tk.Label(self, text=self.w1.get(), fg = 'red', font=('Times', 60))
    self.bmp_number.place(x = 725, y = 140)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = App()
  app.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Glad I could help.